# Axler's Proof that Countably Infinite Sets have Outer Measure 0

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, geometric-series, outer-measure

I am using Axler's new book Measure, Integration & Real Analysis in my Real Variables class. The spirit of the proof below makes perfect sense but there's a minor detail that's bothering me -- shouldn't $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \ell(I_k)=4\epsilon$ not $2\epsilon$?

$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \ell(I_k)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} {\epsilon\over{2^k}}+{\epsilon\over{2^k}}=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} {2\epsilon\over{2^k}}=2\epsilon\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} {1\over{2^k}}=2\epsilon({1\over{1-{1\over{2}}}})= 4\epsilon$

Am I going crazy?

[image]

Comment: You applied the sum of geometric series formula wrong. The first term is $\frac12$, meaning that it should be $=2\epsilon(\frac{1/2}{1-1/2})$

Comment: You are incorrect, the result should be $$2\epsilon\left(\frac{\frac12}{1-\frac12}\right)=2\epsilon$$ your answer would be correct if the sum started at $k=0.$

Comment: @jmars I am trying to keep track of where my book Measure, Integration & Real Analysis is being used as a textbook. Could you let me know  your university (email to measure@axler.net or add a comment in response to this comment). Thanks!